# element(by.binding('binding-name')) fails, while element(by.css('ng-bind="binding-name"')) works fine

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

What can be reasons for `element(by.binding('binding-name'))` failing? It throws error

> Failed: Expected 'by.binding("binding-name")' to be present and visible. After 1659 driverWaitIterations. Last webdriver error: Error: Wait timed out after 40003ms

But if I change it to `element(by.css('ng-bind="binding-name"'))`, it works fine.

This is used in logout function of my test

```
function logOut() {

element(by.binding('binding-name')).click() //works fine with element(by.css('ng-bind="binding-name"'))
    .then(function () {
        return element(by.css('[ng-click="LogOut()"]')).waitReady();
    }).then(function (tab) {
        return tab.click();
    });
}
```

Also, I have not changed anything in ignoreSynchronization flag.

Comment: `Failed: Expected 'by.binding("binding-name")' to be present and visible` does not look like a regular error in Protractor you would get when using `element(by.binding('binding-name')).click()`..are you sure the error is thrown on this particular line? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any additional modules on top of protractor?

Comment: @alecxe- I am using protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter . Do you think that can cause anything?

Comment: @alecxe- The error looks like in the same line, as I dont have anything else with similar binding-name. Also, upon changing it to webdriver api by.css('ng-app="binding-name"'), it worked. :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @sanja 's answer, I got direction that - there is something wrong in angular's  `binding` tag.

When I did more detailed inspection I found out that I called `debugInfoEnabled(false)` for performance boost on my production environment but it is having adverse effect on protractor's APIs. ( Actually, thats the whole point of debugInfoEnabled)

Thank you all for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try with waiting:

```
 browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.binding("binding-name"))), 30000).then(function () {
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.binding("binding-name"))), 30000).then(function () {
      element(by.binding('binding-name')).click();

});
});
```

It might find it quickly the element and tries to click it before it is present in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
element(by.binding('binding-name')).then(function(ele){
      ele.click();
    });
```